# How to render images with react on server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, reactjs, express

How can I render images and css files on server side with React?

Here is my server code:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom/server');

import Master from '../../../client/Master'

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('test.html', {reactOutput: ReactDOM.renderToString(<Master/>)});
});
```

Master component:

```
import React from "react";
import Intro from "./pages/Intro";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Header from "./components/Header";

export default class Master extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {appStatus: 'INTRO'}
    }

    render() {
        let layout;
        switch (this.state.appStatus) {
            case "INTRO":
                layout = <Intro/>;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
                {layout}
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

But when I run server with babel I got this error:

> /assets/img/logo.png: Unexpected character '?' (1:0)

And this is the Header component which tries to require logo.

```
import React from "react";
**import logo  from '../../assets/img/logo.png';**

export default class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">**<img width="250" src={logo} alt=""/></a>**
                    </div>


                </div>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}
```

But it works fine with webpack for client side..

Comment: I know it's old but did you figure this out in the end? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

### You need a separate webpack config for your server

1. #### Install this module to exclude node_modules:

   ```
   npm install --save webpack-node-externals
   ```
2. #### Create a separate webpack config for your server:

   ```
   module.exports = {    
     const path = require('path')
     const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

     context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'directory of your server file'),
     entry: ['./filename of your server file'],
     output: {
       path: path.join(__dirname, 'directory of your bundled file'),
       filename: 'filename of your bundled file'
     },
     target: 'node',
     externals: [nodeExternals()],
     module: {
       rules: [
         {
           test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
           use: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
         }
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
3. #### Here's an example server webpack.config.js:

   ```
   module.exports = {    
     const path = require('path')
     const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

     context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
     entry: ['./index.js'],
     output: {
       path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
       filename: 'bundle.js'
     },
     target: 'node',
     externals: [nodeExternals()],
     module: {
       rules: [
         {
           test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
           use: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
         }
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
4. #### If using the above webpack.config.js example, run webpack then the compiled server file:

   ```
   webpack
   node dist/bundle.js
   ```

Comment: It's not working for me. The result is the images on output path and the src looking for it as `'src='2013068ae43bfc8883afa52e781eef49.jpg'`. But if I'm not on the root route it's resolved as `http://localhost:3000/receitas/2013068ae43bfc8883afa52e781eef49.jpg` which is not the file location.

Comment: When I try to get this URL `http://localhost:3000/receitas/2013068ae43bfc8883afa52e781eef49.jpg` or this one `http://localhost:3000/2013068ae43bfc8883afa52e781eef49.jpg` the result is not the image nor NOT FOUND. It's the index.js server side rendered

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is either old or has a couple issues. [Here](https://github.com/machinsk/react-pdf-renderer-server-example/tree/import-local-files) is a updated answer for webpack 5. This imports fonts and images from their respective folders.

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  target: "node",
  entry: {
    server: "./server.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname),
    filename: "[name]-packed.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'img/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'fonts/'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention that `file-loader` is deprecated in WP5 - https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#file-loader - WP5 mentions that deprecated features are removed. So im unsure if the behavior works as expected - https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/#make-sure-your-build-has-no-errors-or-warnings