# How to use static media assets generated by CRA’s npm build in SSR mode?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have a standard TypeScript React app created using CRA.

It uses Helmet for metadata and styled-components for styling.

I am currently using Babel and express to serve the app. Most things work fine, but imported image assets do not work in SSR mode.

For example, `import sun from "../images/sun.jpg"` is rendered as `[object Object]` instead of `data:image/jpeg;base64,...` and `import backgroundS from "../images/background-1280x720.jpg"` as `[object Object]` instead of `/static/media/background-1280x720.702f9ac6.jpg`.

```
import sun from "../images/sun.jpg"

const ImageComponent = () => (
  <img src={sun} /> // In SSR mode, this is rendered as <img src="[object Object]">
)
```

I am just getting started with React SSR so I am probably missing a few key pieces of knowledge to figure this out. I spend more than two hours trying to find a solution.

What am I missing?

## index.js

```js
"use strict"

require("ignore-styles")

require("@babel/register")({
  ignore: [/(node_modules)/],
  presets: [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
  ],
  extensions: [".tsx"],
  cache: false,
})

require("./server")
```

## server.js

```js
"use strict"

const dotenv = require("dotenv").config()
const express = require("express")
const path = require("path")
const fs = require("fs")
const renderToString = require("react-dom/server").renderToString
const React = require("react")
const Helmet = require("react-helmet").default
const ServerStyleSheet = require("styled-components").ServerStyleSheet
const StaticRouter = require("./src/routers/Static").default

const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, "build/index.html")

const server = express()

server.disable("x-powered-by")

const middleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
  let context = {}
  let html = renderToString(
    sheet.collectStyles(
      React.createElement(StaticRouter, {
        location: req.url,
        context: context,
      })
    )
  )
  const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic()
  const styleTags = sheet.getStyleTags()
  if (context.url) {
    res.redirect(context.url)
  } else if (!fs.existsSync(indexPath)) {
    next("Site is updating... please reload page in a few minutes.")
  } else {
    let index = fs.readFileSync(indexPath, "utf8")
    let status = 200
    if (typeof context.status === "number") {
      status = context.status
    }
    return res.status(status).send(
      index
        .replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${html}</div>`)
        .replace("</head>", `${helmet.meta.toString()}</head>`)
        .replace("</head>", `${helmet.title.toString()}</head>`)
        .replace("</head>", `${helmet.script.toString()}</head>`)
        .replace("</head>", `${styleTags}</head>`)
    )
  }
}

// This line is required by SSR
server.get("/", middleware)

server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")))

server.get("*", middleware)

server.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing webpack there? After a quick look, found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45173963

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @dougg0k. I stumbled upon similar solutions but looks like they suggest using two separate webpack configs which builds the bundles twice (once for the server and once for the browser)... Is this really necessary? How would that work in the context of an isomorphic app?

Comment: Ur Welcome. But that I am not sure, I never build a webpack isomorphic solution before, only with CSR. I actually prefer to use Next.js for SSR. What I know is that, the import magic is related to Webpack.

Comment: @sunknudsen in my opinion having separate webpack configs for your server and client is not a big factor. you're only executing a build at 'build' time, not at 'run' time so aside from the time it takes to build your bundles and having to maintain two separate files, i haven't experienced any issues. it works just fine in the context of an isomorphic app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to solve this question, please submit an answer!

That being said, it is perhaps not solvable so here is a workaround.

I ended up moving my image assets to `public/static/media` and using absolute `src` paths over imports and SSR works once I run `npm build`!

```
const ImageComponent = () => (
  <img src="/static/media/sun.jpg" />
)
```